# How to find 2 or more consecutive words which are in caps whereas remaining words are non-caps

Tags: regex, text, information-retrieval

I am trying to solve this problem using RegExp. I am sure this could be easily solved in Java and many other language. But, I want to use this example to further learn about RegExp

For below 4 input sentences:

```
1. Abc Abcabc 123,00 test ABCDTEST XYZTEST XY 
2. aBC Abcabc 24DD test ABCDTEST XYZTEST XY test is test
3. ABC Abcabc test ABCDTEST XYZTEST
4. ABC ABCABC TEST ABCDTEST XYZTEST
```

I want matching term as:

```
1. ABCDTEST XYZTEST XY 
2. ABCDTEST XYZTEST XY   
3. ABCDTEST XYZTEST      (only two in end satisfies condition)         
4.                       (no match, because all of them are in caps)
```

It would be helpful get start offset and end offset of the matching term.

For simplicity, lets assume there will only one match be present.
i.e there won't be any input like this

```
 5. Abc Abcabc 123,00 test ABCDTEST XYZTEST XY  agab WXYZ ABCDE
```

But, extra credit if you can solve this too.

Here is how my initial regex looks like (which is wrong)

```
(([A-Z]+){2}){2}
```

Comment: I'm sorry what exactly are you trying to match - a string of ALL CAPS that has at least 1 lower case before it?  Are you trying to get alphabetical strings in all uppercase??

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear with all the examples. I am trying to match words of ALL CAPS in consecutive order ex: "ABC ABC" doesn't matter if there is 1 lower case before it or not.

Comment: @Watt: the multiple match thing is driving me crazy: here for more on the subject http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842595/how-to-match-all-uppercase-words-only-if-theres-a-lowercase-in-the-string .

Answer (score 1):

If there won't be two matching pattern in one line:

```
^(?=.*[a-z]).*?(\b[A-Z]+(?:\h+[A-Z]+\b)+)
```

will store the result in the first captured group. If your string is multiline and you want to consider it line by line, use the `g` (don't stop at first match) and `m` (multiline) flags.

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/qC2wF9

**Explanation**

- `^(?=.*[a-z])`: checks, from the beginning of the line, that there is at least one lowercase letter.
- `(\b[A-Z]+(?:\h+[A-Z]+\b)+)`:

  - `\b[A-Z]+`: checks that there is an all-caps word...
  - `\h+[A-Z]+\b`: ...separated by at least a space (`\h` is short for horizontal space, ie whitespaces, tabs... but no newline) from another all-caps word...
  - `(?:\h+[A-Z]+\b)+`: ...possibly followed by other all-caps words (`(?: )` is a non-capturing group)

**Warning**

The `\b` will allow stuff like `abc-ABD ABD`. If there a risk of that happening, you can replace the regex with:

```
^(?=.*[a-z]).*?((?:^|\h+)[A-Z]+(?:\h+[A-Z]+(?=\h+|$))+)
```

**Improvement**

This is by no mean pretty, nor does it solve the "two matches in one line" problem. Feel free to comment!

Comment: +1 thanks for a detailed explanation. Your regex might require minor tweak.. for some reason, it is matching first word of example 3, whereas in that example 4th and 5th word should match. Please see here http://rubular.com/r/Fzb95WoNzd

Comment: But, I see your demo shows it matches correctly. So, there might be an issue with rubular; not with your solution. Ignore my earlier comment. I will try it my java code accept the answer once I get it working. I learned many new things today about RegExp.

Comment: I believe Rubular doesn't know the word boundary `\b`, and treats it like a regular escaped `b`...

Answer (score 0):

```
\b([A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z])+)\b
```

will match 2 or more all caps words

So, it would handle your cases 1-3, but not 4

I can't think how to do (4) yet - but I'll think about it some more

Comment: Thanks. I tried to test your solution.. please click on this link http://rubular.com/r/940qsHaSMG not sure why none matches

Comment: You probably made a typo and forgot a plus sign: `(?:\s+[A-Z]+)` in the middle of the regex. This works to find two or more uppercase words, but indeed doesn't check the lowercase thing... Also be careful as it will match `123-ABC DEF#456`

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
[a-z]+[^A-Z]*\s([A-Z]+\s[A-Z\s]+)
```

http://regex101.com/r/lR3nN5

Comment: It doesn't work if the lowercase part isn't directly before the uppercase part. Nor does it check if there are two consecutive uppercase words :/

Comment: It does check for 2 uppercase.

Comment: It breaks on `abB ABD ABD` and on `ab ABC  a` (with two whitespaces between `ABC` and `a`, removed by SO comment markup) :/

Answer (score 0):

This may work but it might be alot to grasp if you are just learning.
Regex:

```
 (?!^[^\S\n]*(?:[A-Z]+[^\S\n]*)*$)^.*?(?:^|(?<=[^\S\n]))([A-Z]+(?:[^\S\n]+[A-Z]+){1,})(?=[^\S\n]|$)
```

Explained:

```
 # Modifier: multi-line mode  '(?m)'
 (?!                           # Ensure this is not a line of all caps (via assertion)
      ^                             # Beginning of line
      [^\S\n]* 
      (?: [A-Z]+ [^\S\n]* )*
      $                             # End of line
 )
 ^                             # Begining of line. Ok, this is a good candidate, check it 
 .*?                           # Slowly, creep up on it
 (?:                           # Here, the candidate must be qualified (via assertion)
      ^                             # Either start of the line
   |                              # or
      (?<= [^\S\n] )                # A non-newline whitespace separatore before us
 )
 (                             # (1 start), Capture our candidate
      [A-Z]+                        # First of all caps
      (?: [^\S\n]+ [A-Z]+ ){1,}     # Second to more all caps
 )                             # (1 end)
 (?= [^\S\n] | $ )             # Found them, but have to qualify  (via assertion)
                               #  there is a valid separator after us,
                               #  either non-newline whitespace or End of line
```