# Match all uppercase words only if there's a lowercase in the string, with one regex

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

I stumbled upon this seemingly trivial question, and I'm stuck on it. I have a string, in which I want to match **in one regex** all uppercase words *only* if somewhere in the string there's at least a lowercase letter.

Basically, I want each of these lines (we can consider I'll apply the regex to each line separately, no need for some multiline handling) to output:

```
ab ABC          //matches or captures ABC
ab ABC 12 CD    //matches or captures ABC, CD
ABC DE          //matches or captures nothing (no lowercase)
ABC 23 DE EFG a //matches or captures ABC, DE, EFG
AB aF DE        //matches or captures AB, DE
```

I am using PCRE as regex flavor (I know some other flavors allow for variable length look-behind).

**Update after comments**

Obviously, there are lots of easy solutions if I use multiple regex or the program language I'm using to call the regex (e.g. first validate the string by looking for a lowercase letter then match all uppercase words with two different regex).

My goal here is to find a way to do it with one regex.

I have no technical imperative for this constraint. Take it as an exercise of style if you have to, or curiosity, or me trying to up my regex skills: the task seemed (at first) *so* simple that I'd like to know if one regex alone can achieve it. If it can't, I'd like to understand why.

Or if it can but regex aren't designed for these kind of tasks, I wish I'd  know why - or at least what are "these kind of unsuited tasks", so that I can choose the right solution when I meet them.

---

So, is it doable in one regex?

Comment: Why not doing something simple with the language you are using. PHP: `if(preg_match('/[a-z]/', $string) { $string = strtoupper($string); }`

Comment: I know it's a long question but please read the disclaimer part: many easy practical solutions if we do not limit to pure regex, I want to know if this is doable in **one** regex.

Comment: I don't think so.  Regex essentially returns either "matches" or "not matches" and we have 2 kinds of matching statuses: whether the entire expr matches lowercase and where the uppercase words are.  You need separate Regex to perform these separate matches.

Comment: My bad!  I was just skimming through quickly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**
So `\G` initially is set to a matched condition at position 0.
Which means in multi-line mode, BOS has to be a special case.
Even though BOString is a BOLine, if the assertion `(?= ^ .* [a-z] )` fails,
`\G` is initially set as matched (default?) and UC words are found without being validated.

```
(?|(?=\A.*[a-z]).*?\b([A-Z]+)\b|(?!\A)(?:(?=^.*[a-z])|\G.*?\b([A-Z]+)\b))
```

**Update 2** *Posted for posterity.*
After some discussion with @Robin, the above regex can be refactored to this:

```
 #  (?:(?=^.*[a-z])|(?!\A)\G).*?\b([A-Z]+)\b

 (?:
      (?= ^ .* [a-z] )        # BOL, check if line has lower case letter
   |                        # or
      (?! \A )                # Not at BOS (beginning of string, where \G is in a matched state)
      \G                      # Start the match at the end of last match (if previous matched state)
 )
 .*? \b 
 ( [A-Z]+ )              # (1), Found UC word
 \b
```

Perl test case:

```
$/ = undef;

$str = <DATA>;

@ary = $str =~ /(?:(?=^.*[a-z])|(?!\A)\G).*?\b([A-Z]+)\b/mg;

print "@ary", "\n-------------\n";

while ($str =~ /(?:(?=^.*[a-z])|(?!\A)\G).*?\b([A-Z]+)\b/mg)
{
   print "$1 ";
}

__DATA__
DA EFR
ab ABC
ab ABC 12 CD
ABC DE  t
ABC 23 DE EFG a
```

Output >>

```
ABC ABC CD ABC DE ABC DE EFG
-------------
ABC ABC CD ABC DE ABC DE EFG
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, it [seems to break](http://regex101.com/r/yF5eE8) if the string is *only* `A BC`: it shouldn't select anything but it does. As I'm not very comfortable around `\G` (and don't fully understand *yet* why your regex seems to work in other cases) I don't know if that's a hard-to-fix issue. BTW I guess *for now* the answer doesn't need to be multiline, we can take each line separately. Also I'm not sure if you really need the last non-capturing parenthesis.

Comment: Yep, I think it holds! Thanks for the multiline solution. Few comments: 1.I believe the regex could, strictly speaking, be refactored as `(?:(?=\A.*[a-z])|(?!\A)(?:(?=^.*[a-z])|(?!^)\G)).*?\b([A-Z]+)\b`. 2.Regarding the default matching of `\G`, if think the check could be done as so: `(?:(?=^.*[a-z])|(?!^)\G).*?\b([A-Z]+)\b`, as a BOS is a BOL. Do you agree?

Comment: @Robin - Answer to **1** No reason to add `(?!^)`, taking it out it could be refactored to `(?:(?=\A.*[a-z])|(?!\A)(?:(?=^.*[a-z])|\G)).*?\b([A-Z]+)\b`. Answer to **2** The only reason for this `(?=^.*[a-z])|(?!^)\G)` is to flip the _nitial_ regex startup matched state of `\G` to `unmatched`. Thats it, nothing more. After that is done, this works `(?:(?=^.*[a-z])|\G.*?\b([A-Z]+)\b)` because `\G` naturally goes into an unmatched state. The `(?!^)\G` is just a shortcut for whats really happening, but not necessary after getting to first `unmatched` state.

Comment: @Robin - So, just for reference, the docs say `\G` is used to chain multiple regex's on the same string starting from the end of the last match. By default then, on a new regex, `\G` is initially in the matched state. So there always has to be a way to _thwart_ that condition because the engine will always try to consume something if it can. And you give it as a first option to consume nothing (ie: an assertion) or to consume something (`\Gsomething`) its gonna take the something every time. Bearing that in mind, you've just mastered the `\G` anchor.

Comment: I agreed for **1**. Regarding **2**, if I understand well the `(?!^)\G` is only useful in case there aren't any lowercase: without this check, the `\G` would be matched at the BOL and everythg would be wrongly validated. After that, the check is useless. But it's the same "useless" (one time use) thing that happens with the `(?!\A)` structure, right? Wouldn't the `(?!^)\G` be more concise then? **3**. BTW in your solution, at the beginning of a newline the `\G` doesn't match because of the `\n` between the end of last match and new BOL, so no need for `(?!^)`? Thx for your enlightenment!

Comment: @Robin - Hi Robin. Answer's: **2.** I'm not sure what the definition of _'concise'_ is in this context. However, in this case, `(?!\A)\G` is _more correct_, more exact representation of what the intention is. When not using `\G` for chaining regex's and in a single/multi-lined (mode) string `\A` is clearly more relavent than `^`, otherwise this `(?:(?=^.*[a-z])|(?!\A)\G).*?\b([A-Z]+)\b` wouldn't work, it does, and more importantly, it demistifies the _magic_ of `\G`. **3.** Correct. and for that reason, %90 of the time `(?!\A)\G` is all thats ever needed, if at all.

Answer (score 1):

Silly questions deserve silly answers.

```
/(?{ @matches = m{\b\p{Lu}+\b}g if m{\p{Ll}} })/;
```

Test:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

while (<DATA>) {
   chomp;

   local our @matches;
   /(?{ @matches = m{\p{Lu}+}g if m{\p{Ll}} })/;

   say "$_: ", join ', ', @matches;
}

__DATA__
ab ABC
ab ABC 12 CD
ABC DE
ABC 23 DE EFG a
```

---

And now for the silly answer I promised:

```
my @matches = /
   \G
   (?: (?! ^ )
   |   (?= .* \p{Ll} )
   )
   .*? ( \b \p{Lu}+ \b )
/sg;
```

which condenses to

```
my @matches = /\G(?:(?!^)|(?=.*\p{Ll})).*?(\b\p{Lu}+\b)/sg;
```

At the start of the string, it looks ahead for a lower-case. Anywhere else, there's no need to check since we already checked.

Comment: Thank you ! I am more interested in the "silly answer" indeed. Just two comments: 1. I am interested in each line separatly, not multiline, so I believe the `s` flag isn't necessary. 2. This will currently break on `AB aC BD`, selecting the `C` while I only want full uppercase words. **But** I believe `/\G(?:(?!^)|(?=.*\p{Ll})).*?\b(\p{Lu}+)\b/g` solves it all. Thanks !

Comment: Don't take out the `^`; add `/m`. Don't replace `\P{Lu}*` which much fragile `.*?`. `.*?` is something you very much want to avoid.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. 1. The `^` hasn't changed as far as I can tell, there is just no multiline in my question: I'd like a solution for one line (let's say I apply the regex to each line of the example snippet separately) 2. I don't feel so good about `.*?`, either. But your current solution, when given `AB aC AD` will output `AB`, `C`, `AD` (or just `AB` if I add word boundaries) instead of `AB`, `AD`. Any idea how to fix that? **edit:** maybe this wasn't clear so I updated the question to reflect this comment.

Comment: Re: "just no multiline in my question", then why would you want to check for newlines? Keep the `/s`.

Comment: ug, The fact that `.*?` makes it so much simpler is another sign that this is a completely incorrect approach.

Comment: 1.If it's on one line, why should I keep the `/s`? The dot doesn't need match newlines. Is it some kind of best practice? 2. Yeah, I get that this question isn't really popular. Maybe because obviously, using two regex would be more efficient/simple. What I don't get is why it is such a silly question/incorrect approach. Regex are a powerful tool and the original question doesn't seem complicated. Aren't they designed for this kind of task, if so what is this "unsuited kind"? Why is that approach so wrong? I genuinely want to understand more about these questions as I they aren't obvious to me

Comment: Re "why should I keep the /s?" Why would you want to check for newlines if there aren't going to be any.

Comment: Because the *answer* is extremely needlessly complicated. Hours has already been spent on the initial coding. That doesn't even factor in future costs.

Comment: Maybe you don't know what `.` and/or `/s` does? `/s` makes `.` match any character. Without `/s`, it's short for `[^\n]`

Comment: Yeah...Why bother to make `.` aware of `\n` if there aren't gonna be any? To me your arguments point towards *not* using the `/s`, keeping it *is* checking for newlines. Regarding the impracticability of the code, take it as an exercise of style if you will, then. I feel like everyone here dismissed the question as obviously "silly", but strange constraints don't always equal absurd question. "What if we had to do it in one regex" is a big IF, but other than "it could be easily done another way" I don't see why it is such an uninteresting question. Thanks for the answer anyway, I learnt a lot.

Comment: Re "Yeah...Why bother to make `.` aware of `\n` if there aren't gonna be any?" Exactly. `/.../` makes it needlessly aware, and `/.../s` spares that waste.

Comment: I think I see what you mean: with `/s`, `.` is a *full wildcard*, whereas without `/s` it treats `\n` differently, a distinction which is useless. I thought it wasn't necessary to add a character in order to match something that won't be here, but I see how we can consider that cleaner.

Comment: Not cleaner, faster. Why check for newlines if there aren't going to be any. e.g. `/.{5}/s` can simply check if the length of the string, but `/.{5}/` also needs to check if those characters are newlines. (Ok, cleaner too as far as I'm concerned. I keep asking myself "did he really meant to exclude newlines there?" without the `s`.)

Comment: Didn't think of it that way, I was under the impression you wanted the regex to be able to match linebreaks that would never be there. This is a valid point, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that can be done, but here is some background information, explaining the "Why?" part a bit.

Regexes were designed to match *[regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)*, and originally, that's all they could do. In fact, regular grammars are among the simplest that aren't completely trivial; most modern computer languages use non-regular grammars, for instance. (See, especially, [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Expressive_power_and_compactness).)

So, there is a limit to what kind of languages a regex can describe, and it is far more limited that what you can describe with some simple English sentences, for example.

The [Chomsky hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy#The_hierarchy) is a way to classify languages into different levels of expressiveness. Note that regular grammars are all the way at the bottom, and most useful (programming) languages are either Type 3, or borderline Type-3 (i.e. with a few Type-3 parts added in). This is due to a simple fact: our brains are quite capable of processing context-sensitive (Type-3) grammars, even complex ones (so we want programming languages to be powerful). However, computer parsers for context sensitive grammars are quite a bit slower than those for Type-2 (so, we want programming languages to be limited in power!

For regexes, which are expected to match very quickly, it's even more important to limit their overall expressiveness. But, by writing two or more regexes with some control-structure added, you are effectively expanding them to be more powerful than a *regular* expression parser.

Comment: Thank you for that clear explanation, especially of why two regex can be *inherently* more powerful than one. One detail: in the wiki article, I believe Types are ordered the other way around (T3: regular, T0: Turing complete). In my case though, an answer does seem to exist (currently discussing `/(?:(?=^.*[a-z])|(?!^)\G).*?\b([A-Z]+)\b/gm` with @sln)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe we're over thinking things:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use strict;
use feature qw(say);
use autodie;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

while ( my $string = <DATA> ) {
    chomp $string;
    my @array;
    say qq(String: "$string");
    if ( @array = $string =~ /(\b[A-Z]+\b)/g ) {
        say qq(String groups: ) . join( ", ", @array ) . "\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
ab ABC
ab ABC 12 CD
ABC DE
ABC 23 DE EFG a
AB aF DE
ADSD asd ADSD
asd ADSDSD
SDSD SDD SD
SSDD SDS asds
```

The output:

```
String: "ab ABC"
String groups: ABC

String: "ab ABC 12 CD"
String groups: ABC, CD

String: "ABC DE"
String groups: ABC, DE

String: "ABC 23 DE EFG a"
String groups: ABC, DE, EFG

String: "AB aF DE"
String groups: AB, DE

String: "ADSD asd ADSD"
String groups: ADSD, ADSD

String: "asd ADSDSD"
String groups: ADSDSD

String: "SDSD SDD SD"
String groups: SDSD, SDD, SD

String: "SSDD SDS asds"
String is groups: SSDD, SDS
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input. I am looking for a way to match these words **in one regex** (non-negotiable constraint). You're not the only one who took my question that way, so I believe it wasn't well formed and I've updated it. I hope it is clearer.

Comment: Um, but I'm using a single regex: `/(\b[A-Z]+\b)/g`. You're not trying to match all of the lines at once. Are you?

Comment: Woops, my turn to read too fast :/ I need to match uppercase words *only* on lines that have at least one lowercase letter, so `AB EF` shouldn't match anything, but `AB cD EF` should match `AB` and `EF`.

Answer (score -2):

One regex:

```
@words = split (/[a-z]+/, $_);
```

Comment: Huuum... How would that select uppercase words on lines containing a lowercase?